# How to turn off Bread Crumb

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

I am learning **version 1.9.**

How to turn off **bread crumb**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go To `Admin-->System --> Web --> Default Pages --> Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages to Set  "NO".`

Comment: @ Mrunmay Deswandikar  Any Time .

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove **breadcrumbs** from site add below code in your local.xml file in current theme

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">            
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
        </reference>       
    </default> 
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

1. If you want to remove the Breadcrumbs from all dynamic pages, use the code below in `local.xml`:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <layout version="0.1.0">
         <default>
            <reference name="root">            
               <remove name="breadcrumbs" />
            </reference>       
         </default> 
      </layout>
   ```

**For other pages like below:**

```
    <layout>
      <!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product view page -->
      <catalog_product_view>
         <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
      </catalog_product_view>
      <!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product list pages -->
      <catalog_category_default>
         <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
      </catalog_category_default>    
    </layout>
```

Now refresh your Magento Cache from the admin panel and refresh the browser cache as well to see the changes.

---

**Method 2**

Go to the app/design/frontend/default/* (your current theme)/layout/ directory

Open page.xml (if not there, copy from base directory) and comment the following:

Change:

```
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

To:

```
<!-- <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it in cms pages

`System >> Web >> Default Pages >> Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages` and select no if you don't want them in any of cms pages

**Second Method:**

Create a local.xml file `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

**For any other pages use**

```
 <layout>
<!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product view page -->
<catalog_product_view>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_product_view>
<!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product list pages -->
<catalog_category_default>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_category_layered>
 </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to go to:
System --> Web --> Default Pages --> Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages
and turn them off.

e.g /app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATE/layout/local.xml

```
<!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from CMS view page -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>

<layout>
<!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product view page -->
<catalog_product_view>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_product_view>
<!-- this part removes breadcrumbs from product list pages -->
<catalog_category_default>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
     <remove name="breadcrumbs"/>
</catalog_category_layered>
 </layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Can you please accept this answer as the best so I can get public appreciation.